# How to call out from a Clojure web-framework (eg Pedestal) to an out-of-process backend listening on TCP?

Tags: clojure

I want to keep my business-logic tier pure and unpolluted from transport protocols such as http. To that end I want to use Pedestal as (imho) it should be used: namely to provide a point of access for incoming http requests, to provide routing and the rendering of responses (be that html or well-formed restful data) but not to do any hint of business-logic or database access. What business is it of the web-tier to even know a database exists?

Call me old fashioned, but to my "pre-web-rules-everything-and-is-King-above-all-else" mindset, business logic should NEVER be running in the same O/S process as the web-tier. In fact, it should not even be on the same box. To that end, **is there a canonical way to call out from Clojure web-frameworks (like Pedestal) to a backend service running on TCP, either across a domain socket or a 'nix socket. Is FastCGI still an option here?**

I envisage an http request coming in to Pedestal. Pedestal then routes it to the correct function. This function fires off an async call to the business-logic-tier by sending an http-neutral message (that is to say, nothing about **how** the original request was received is included) over TCP. The business-logic-tier does its thing and returns another neutral message containing just data to the calling Pedestal function which then hands the data off to renders etc and the http response is built and sent back to the client. (Authentication etc left out for brevity.)

In my mind’s eye, the Pedestal code should be dead simple, stateless and clean. It just routes http requests to ‘neutral message dispatch code’ and then renders the result. In essence, the web-tier should be a very thin layer with absolutely no brains. The business-tier should be 100% agnostic to http. It should be running on a separate process. The development team on that code could potentially have never even heard of http or the cursed ‘web’.

So, how do I achieve this web-less nirvana? Or more accurately, how do I put the darn ‘web’ back in its box all the while using uber-awsome Clojure. Thanks.

Comment: Unless I missed the essence of your questions, seems like you have a pretty well defined separation of concerns (SoC) policy already. Calling out from Clojure is then a matter of choice of library. In other words, as the Clojure code is simply choice of the surrogate/proxy for the "back-end(s)", for example `clj-http`.